# Roslyn, passing values through hostObject

Tags: c#, session, roslyn, scriptengine

I am trying to send one class through hostObject but apparently it doesn't want to work:

```
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Scripting;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;


public class ShippingService
{
    public class ShippingDetails//class that I want to send
    {
        public decimal total { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string destination { get; set; }
    }
    public static string ShipingCost(decimal total, int quantity, string destination)
    {
        var details = new ShippingDetails
        {
            total = total,
            quantity = quantity,
            destination = destination
        };

        try
            {
                ScriptEngine roslynEngine = new ScriptEngine();
                Roslyn.Scripting.Session session = roslynEngine.CreateSession(details);
                session.AddReference(details.GetType().Assembly);
                session.AddReference("System.Web");
                session.ImportNamespace("System");
                session.ImportNamespace("System.Web");
                var result = session.Execute("details.destination");
                return result;
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            return e.Message;
            }
        return "";
    }   

}
```

When I am calling the function destination is for example "France", and I should get this value in result but i am getting mistake:

> Roslyn.Compilers.CompilationErrorException: (1,1): error CS0103: The name 'details' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is exactly right. When you have a host object, you can't access it by the name of the local variable that holds it in your method (how would that even work? how would `ScriptEngine` learn that name?).

Instead, you can access the host object *directly*, almost as if you were writing a member method of that type (but not quite, you can't use `this` or access non-public members).

This means that you should write just:

```
session.Execute("destination")
```

BTW, according to .Net naming guidelines, names of public properties should start with upper case letter (e.g. `Destination`).